# Symlinks and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing

Tags: magento, fonts

I have a main site forexample.com, and then I have a second site, forinstance.com.

Both use the same Magento system, but forinstance.com is pointing to all the files in forexample.com using symlinks. This is using Magento for a multi-site.

For forinstance.com, I wanted to add fonts to the font folder (which I thought was shared) and link to it. Unfortunately, with Magento, it seems that if you want to link to something in Magento, you have to link from the main site, not the site you want to use. If I want to use the images folder for forinstance.com, I have to link http://forexample.com/images instead ( I must have it setup wrong). Otherwise, I get a 404 if I link to the images folder using http://forinstance.com

From the CSS I can link to forexample.com just fine. However with fonts, I try to link to http://forexample.com/fonts/font.ttf and i get this error:

> Redirect at origin 'http://forexample.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://forinstance.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I can understand that since its not the same URL the browser wouldn't want you to steal from another site, but they're using the same CMS. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this probably won't work for everything (like dynamic image folders where product images are added), but I simply added a fonts folder to the add-on domain's folder in the server (duh). This way, the fonts are directly in the folder of the domain and there's no need for symlinks.

So instead of trying to reference fonts from the main site through symlinks, I added a folder:

```
/forinstance.com/
    /admin
    /images
    /forexample.com/ (addon domain)
        /fonts (new folder inside)
    /resources
        /logs
        /svgs
    /fonts (main folder)
```

Hope that some how makes sense.